# Javascript date format issues

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format a date in js with "mmdd" format as the final result.

If I set `var s = ""` i reach my alert, but if i do not, the code does not run.

any pointers would be appreciated!

```
            function stateChange(e){
                var p = (document.getElementById("stateSelect").value);
                var t = new Date();
                var s = t.format("mmdd");
                alert(s);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function format for a date in javascript.

Below is a link to a page with 10 different ways to format dates in javascript:
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

**EDIT**

The below also looks promising to use to get what you're after:

http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Never used it but probably will... :)

Comment: It hasn't been updated for a while, but I've sworn by it for any of my projects which have needed complex date transforms and displays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : ''+n}

var t = new Date();
var s=pad(t.getMonth()+1)+pad(t.getDate());
alert(s);
```